# How to make the view change to a form to create an account when you press the start create account button?

Tags: python, desktop-application, flet

I am making a desktop application which needs a form to log in and create an account. When I start the program, the login form first appears, but what I want is that when they click on the create account button they change to the create an account form.
The code for both the login form and the register form will be provided below. The only thing I need is to program the action of the create account button.

```
#This is login code

import flet
from flet import *


class InputField(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, label, hint_text, marginTop, password=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.body = Container(
            Row(
                controls=[
                    TextField(
                        width=413,
                        height=70,
                        border_radius=10,
                        border_width=2,
                        border_color='#A44BFF',
                        bgcolor='#C4C4C4, 0.1',
                        text_style=TextStyle(color='white'),
                        password=password,
                        label=label,
                        hint_text=hint_text
                    )
                ]
            ),
            margin=margin.only(top=marginTop),
            alignment=alignment.center
        )

    def build(self):
        return self.body



    
def main(page: Page):
    page.title = 'EduConter - Resgistro'
    page.theme_mode = 'DARK'
    page.padding = 0
    page.window_maximized = True
    page.resizable = False
    page.vertical_alignment = 'Center'
    page.horizontal_alignment = 'Center'
    
    
    
    login = Container(
        Stack([
            Image(
                src='./imagenes/fondoLogin.jpg',
            ),
            Container(
                Container(
                    Column(
                        alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                        controls=[
                            Row(
                                alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,

                                controls=[
                                    Image(
                                        src='./imagenes/logoEduConter.png',
                                        width=346,
                                        height=243
                                    )
                                ]
                            ),
                            Row(
                                controls=[
                                    Text(
                                        'Inicio de Sesión',
                                        color='white',
                                        weight='bold',
                                        size=28,
                                    )
                                ]
                            ),
                            InputField('Nombre de Usuario',
                                        'Nombre de Usuario', 21),
                            InputField('Contraseña', 'Contraseña', 0, True),
                            Row(
                                controls=[
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                        content=Text(
                                            'Inicia Sesión',
                                            size=18,
                                            weight='bold'),
                                        width=413,
                                        height=60,
                                        color='white',
                                        bgcolor='#AA16C8, 0.8',
                                        style=ButtonStyle(
                                            side={
                                                '': BorderSide(2, '#A44BFF')
                                            },
                                            shape={
                                                '': RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=10)
                                            }
                                        )
                                    )
                                ]
                            ),
                            Container(
                                Row(
                                    alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                                    spacing=0,
                                    controls=[
                                        Text(
                                            '¿No Tienes Cuenta?',
                                            color='white',
                                            size=14
                                        ),
                                        TextButton(
                                            content=Text(
                                                'Registrate',
                                                color='white',
                                                size=14,
                                                weight='bold',
                                            ),
                                            style=ButtonStyle(
                                                shape={
                                                    '':RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=0)
                                                }
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ]
                                ),
                                margin=margin.only(top=20)
                            )
                        ],
                    ),
                    alignment=alignment.center,
                    width=413,
                    height=page.window_height,
                    expand=True
                ),
                alignment=alignment.center,
            ),
        ]),
        
    )  
    
    page.add(login)
    page.update()
    
flet.app(target=main)




#This is register code

import flet
from flet import *

class InputField(UserControl):
    def __init__(self, label, hint_text, marginTop, password=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.body=Container(
            Row(
                controls=[
                    TextField(
                        width=413,
                        height=70,
                        border_radius=10,
                        border_width=2,
                        border_color='#3733FF',
                        bgcolor='#C4C4C4, 0.1',
                        text_style=TextStyle(color='white'),
                        label=label,
                        hint_text=hint_text,
                        password=password
                    )
                ]
            ),
            alignment=alignment.center,
            margin=margin.only(top=marginTop)
        )
    
    def build(self):
        return self.body
    
    

def main(page: Page):
    page.title = 'EduConter - Resgistro'
    page.theme_mode = 'DARK'
    page.padding = 0
    page.window_maximized = True
    page.resizable = False
    page.vertical_alignment = 'Center'
    page.horizontal_alignment = 'Center'
    
    
    register = Container(
        Stack([
            Image(
                src='./imagenes/fondoRegister.jpg'
            ),
            Container(
                Container(
                    Column(
                        alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                        controls=[
                            Row(
                                controls=[
                                    Text(
                                        'Registro',
                                        color='white',
                                        weight='bold',
                                        size=28
                                    )
                                ]
                            ),
                            InputField(
                                'Nombre Socio Mayoritario',
                                'Nombre Socio Mayoritario',
                                21, 
                                False
                            ),
                            InputField(
                                'Nombre de la Empresa',
                                'Nombre de la Empresa',
                                0,
                                False
                            ),
                            Row(
                                controls=[
                                    Dropdown(
                                        label='Tipo de Sociedad',
                                        hint_text='Tipo de Sociedad',
                                        width=206.5,
                                        height=70,
                                        text_size=18,
                                        bgcolor='#C4C4C4, 0.1',
                                        border_radius=10,
                                        border_width=2,
                                        border_color='#3733FF',
                                        color='white',
                                        hint_style=TextStyle('white'),
                                        options=[
                                            dropdown.Option('Ltda.'),
                                            dropdown.Option('E.U'),
                                            dropdown.Option('S.A.S'),
                                            dropdown.Option('S.A'),
                                            dropdown.Option('S.C')
                                        ]  
                                    ),
                                    Dropdown(
                                        label='Numero de Socios',
                                        hint_text='Numero de Socios',
                                        width=206.5,
                                        height=70,
                                        text_size=18,
                                        bgcolor='#C4C4C4, 0.1',
                                        border_radius=10,
                                        border_width=2,
                                        border_color='#3733FF',
                                        color='white',
                                        hint_style=TextStyle('white'),
                                        options=[
                                           dropdown.Option('1'), 
                                           dropdown.Option('2'), 
                                           dropdown.Option('3'), 
                                           dropdown.Option('4'), 
                                           dropdown.Option('5')
                                        ]
                                    )
                                ]
                            ),
                            InputField(
                                'Contraseña',
                                'La Contraseña debe ser de mínimo 6 carácteres',
                                0,
                                True
                            ),
                            InputField(
                                'Confirmar Contraseña',
                                'Confirmar Contrseña',
                                0,
                                True
                            ),
                            Row(
                                controls=[
                                    Container(
                                        TextButton(
                                            content=Text(
                                                'Registrate',
                                                color='white',
                                                weight='bold',
                                                size=18
                                                ),
                                            width=413,
                                            height=70,
                                            style=ButtonStyle(
                                                color='white',
                                                shape={
                                                    '': RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=8)
                                                }
                                            ),
                                            on_click= lambda e: print('click :)')
                                        ),
                                        width=413,
                                        height=70,
                                        border_radius=10,
                                        border=border.all(2, '#3733FF'),
                                        gradient=LinearGradient(
                                            colors=['#3B7A7A', '#2A68E1, 0.39']
                                        ),
                                        alignment=alignment.center
                                    )
                                ]
                            ),
                            Row(
                                alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                                spacing=0,
                                controls=[
                                    Text(
                                        '¿Tienes Cuentas?,',
                                        color='white',
                                        weight='bold',
                                        size=14
                                    ),
                                    TextButton(
                                        content=Text(
                                            'Inicia Sesión',
                                            color='white',
                                            weight='bold',
                                            size=14
                                        ),
                                        style=ButtonStyle(
                                            shape={
                                                '':RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=0)
                                            }
                                        )
                                    )
                                ]
                            )
                        ]
                    ),
                    alignment=alignment.center,
                    width=413,
                    height=page.window_height,
                    
                ),
                alignment=alignment.center
            ),
            
        ]),
        
    )
    
    page.add(register)
    page.update()

flet.app(target=main)
```

I am new to the world of programming and especially to using the flet tool, so I have not been able to try almost anything